# How to set pathname in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I need to add a chat in my nextjs application and I decided to manage it like twitter. You actually can navigate in your chat from the dashboard and then you can choose between your chats by clicking them and next to the list there opens the actual chat.

I think they use nested routes or something like that because you go from `/messages` to `/messages/{id}` without actually go to a new path.

What I need is on click of the chat I don't want to go to a new route, but I need to load the chat component and set the pathname from ´/messages´ to `/messages/{id}`. This is necessary to keep it open in case of refresh of the page. So is there a way to do that in nextjs? Pushing it to a new route implies to duplicate code which is not a good thing, because I would need to keep all the components that are also in /messages  plus the chat component.

Comment: You can create a file like this: `pages/messages/[[...id]].js`. If your `router.query` object has `id` then render your chat component. If `id` has more than one element then redirect to a 404 or back to `/messages`. Refer - https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes

Comment: It actually works. Thank you! If you want write the answer so I can choose it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use dynamic routes and optional catch all routes (https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#optional-catch-all-routes)

For example, you can create a "messages" folder inside "pages", and create a [[...id]] document (the param inside double brackets is optional).

This way you will be able to have a messages route that may have an id param or not.

And, inside a useEffect for example, once you have fetched your discussions, you can use next router to push your "messages" route with a discussion id and then navigate how you want to.